# How will dagger support jigsaw?

Tags: dagger-2

What are the plans for dagger to support jigsaw in java 9?

1. Can we @Inject across different java 9 modules?
2. Can we @Inject a java 9 service that isn't provided explicitly by dagger?

E.g. module-info.java:

```
module com.foo.bar {
    provides com.foo.api.MyInterface with com.foo.impl.MyImpl;
}
```

and be able to `@Inject MyInterface` without mentioning it in any dagger module.